# google appscript form presenting array values for user selection

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I'm not sure how to code GAS form buttons to fire a script with dynamic values.
In this scenario, the current sheet cell value is used to Look-Up rows in an adjoining sheet and to populate a result array. 
A form then presents a list of buttons containing values from one column of the result array. 
Pressing a form button should fire the script postLocationData, and update the current cell and adjoining cells in the row with result array values, and closes the form. At this point, pressing a form button does not seem to do anything. Much thanks in advance for your help :)

```
function lookUpLocationTest(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var sheetLocations = ss.getSheetByName('LU_Locations');
  var arrayRecords = sheetLocations.getRange(2, 3, sheetLocations.getLastRow(), 2).getValues();


  var matchingLocations=[];
  for (var i=0;i<arrayRecords.length;i++) {
    var result = arrayRecords[i][1].indexOf(cell.getValue())
    if(result !== -1) { 
      matchingLocations.push(arrayRecords[i]);
    }
  }
  if(matchingLocations.length === 0){
    var result = ui.alert(
      'Message:',
      'No Matching Location Found.',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK);
    return 0;
  }      
  Logger.log(' Process - ' + matchingLocations.length + ' Locations have been found.') ; //matchingLocations is a global

  // Prep Form HTML with formatted matching Locations  
  var HTML= '<form><div>'
  for(var i=0;i<matchingLocations.length;i++){
    HTML += "<div><input type='button' value='" + matchingLocations[i][1] 
    + "' onclick='google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(postLocationData).processForm(this.parentNode)'/></div>";
  }
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(HTML).setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  var result = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Matching Locations');

  return 1;
}

function postLocationData(lookUpValue) {
  var location = lookUpValuesInArray (matchingLocations, 1, lookUpValue);  //matchingLocations is a global
  var cell = currCell;
  var latLongCol = 3;
  cell.setValue(location[0][1]);
  cell.getRowIndex();
  var sheet = cell.getSheet();
  sheet.getRange(cell.getRowIndex(), latLongCol).setValue(location[0][0]);
  var temp =1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function "`google.script.run`" will be executed on the client side but it will call a function on the serverside (your .gs file). In this case the function you will call is "processForm()" where you are sending "this.parentNode" as parameter.

In you Apps script file (gs file) you should have a function called  "processForm()" you didn't post it in the example.

After this function ends, if everything went well, the function "`google.script.run`" will execute the function that you defined in "`withSuccessHandler()`".  In you example you used "postLocationData".

This function will receive as parameter the results returned from the execution of processForm().

As I mentioned before `google.script.run` is called on the client side, therefore the function that will be executed if everything went well (the one contained in withSuccessHandler), has to be also in the client side. This means it has to be part of the script contained in the HTML.

As the way you posted the code, I would change the onclick to:

```
onclick='google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(someJavascriptFunction).postLocationData(this.parentNode)
```

withSuccessHandler is optional, if you decided to use it, then you should create a html script tag in you HTML variable having that javascript function to show an alert or something that tells the user the result of clicking the button.

You can also create an html file in the appsscript project and call it like: `HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);`

This way you can have a cleaner html file and the javascript asociated to it.

Hope this helps.